# React Native - android wont compile after adding react-native-firebase

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

My react native android was compiling fine until I added react-native-firebase as per the docs (ios compiles fine).

- React Native 0.63.2 and react-native-firebase 8.3.0 latest versions
  and followed docs very carefully. OSX 10.15.6
- Deleted/cleared/reinstalled gradle and android gradle/build dirs etc.
- java JRE v8.202 `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`
- java JRE v8.202 `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`
- Note that JAVA_HOME path set to `/Applications/AndroidStudio.app/Contents/jre/jd/Contents/Home`

Error:

```
> Task :react-native-firebase_app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm using Mac Bigsur beta 4, and I have the same problem.

I tried uninstalling java by following the steps in this link:

> https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

After that I checked the java version in terminal using: `java -version`.
The uninstall process didn't work. However, running `react-native run-android` now works.

Try this. It may work for you.

Note: If you tried uninstalling java, and running `react-native run-android` still doesn't work, add this to bash_profile and try again: `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/AndroidStudio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: **This worked, but why?** 
<br />
Ok, so I got this error after updating to Big Sur from Catalina. "Uninstalling" _(just following the instructions that SHOULD uninstall Java from the link you mentioned)_ Java worked for me, but I have no idea why. So if there is anyone kind enough to enlighten me I would be so grateful.

Comment: I tried the uninstall (which failed) and java -version showed java was still installed. But my app builds on a device now! Thank you, I have been trying for hours :)

Comment: You saved my day bro, but still don't know, how it suddenly started to work. As you mentioned, this is happened after updating to Big Sur.

Answer (score 3):

Ran `source ~/.bash_profile`  to ensure JAVA_HOME path set to `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home` and it compiled, yay.